# Prevent div from extending scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Take the following example:
https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5079/

Here, you have to scroll down a bit to see the message "Hello!". I also animated a div to move down beyond the screen:

```
$("div").animate({top: '3000px'}, 6000);
```

You can see how the scrollbar changes and we now have a much larger page to scroll through.

Now, I want users to be able to scroll down to the "Hello!" text, if the text is beyond the user's screen. However, I don't want the div to extend the vertical scrollbar once it reaches the bottom of the screen. Rather, I want the div to continue moving down beyond the screen, with the scroll bar remaining unchanged. This way, the scrollbar could not follow it.

Doing "overflow-y: hidden" would prevent users from scrolling downwards on their own choice and reading the "Hello!" Is there anything I can do to accomplish both of these using JS (preferably jQuery) or CSS?

**EDIT:** I still want the div to exist, so I don't want to fade it out. If I had a div that returns afterward or travels in an elliptical orbit, I would like it to still reappear when it reenters the screen, but not to affect the scrollbar.

Comment: If you set the div's position as `fixed` instead of `absolute`, does that solve the problem?

Comment: @RickHitchcock Indeed it does. For my project, I will need the div to be absolute. Is there any way to keep the position the same?

Comment: Could you just make the ball disappear when it passes the 'Hello!'?

Comment: @BlueBoy That's not what I'm asking for either. For example, what if it was supposed to come back up after a few seconds? Or travel in an elliptical orbit that went beyond the screen? I still want the div to exist, but I don't want it to affect the scrollbar.

Comment: I can't think of a way offhand other than putting the div within a fixed-position element.

Comment: Ahh ok, sorry I was confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will make div travel to whatever the Y position of the paragraph is, and after that gets faded out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var p_pos = $("p").offset().top;
    $("div").animate({top: p_pos}, 6000).fadeOut();
});
```

---

Alright, try the following:

```
<div id="everything">
  <div id="orb"></div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br>
  <p>
  Hello!
  </p>
</div>
```

And in your css:

```
#everything {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  max-height: 800px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Make sure to animate $("#orb") instead of just $("div") (and rename it in your css.

Comment: Sorry, not what I'm looking for. I want it to still exist, so if I had a div that comes back or travels in an elliptical orbit, it would leave and re-enter the screen without affecting the scroll bar.

Comment: Have you tried the above? The solution is a little odd since you have strict limitations apparently, but it works.

Comment: Looks pretty good, but is there a way to have other divs on the page that are scrollable, just like the "Hello!" message? https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5085/

Comment: Sure, just make sure it has the same (aside from the height and maybe width) properties as the #everything div.

Comment: Hmm...that doesn't seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5086/
I still can't scroll down to the "block".

Comment: Well yeah, because it's INSIDE of the .everything div, which has a max height of 800px while the #block's top offset is 1000px. Take it out of the previous div.

Answer (score -1):

There you go. Just add to the body and set the div position to

```
body {
overflow: hidden
}
div {
bottom: 0;
}
https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5082/
```

Comment: That completely ignores the first part I asked for. I even said overflow couldn't be used.